# Unable to click on button with span, is there a way in protractor?

Tags: html, button, protractor

Here is my HTML for angular 2 applications. I am executing my tests in Chrome.

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="header-actions">
    <!---->
    <clr-dropdown _ngcontent-c0="" class="dropdown" style="position: static;">
        <button _ngcontent-c0="" class="nav-text dropdown-toggle" 
            clrdropdowntrigger="">
        <span _ngcontent-c0="">User Name</span>
        <!---->
        </button>
        <!---->
    </clr-dropdown>
</div>
```

I have tried the following options, but failed to click on User Name

```
1.1    element(by.css('nav-text dropdown-toggle')).click();
1.2    element(by.css('.nav-text dropdown-toggle')).click();
1.3    element(by.css("//span[. = 'User Name']")).click();
1.4    element(by.xpath("//span[. = 'User Name']")).click();



2. var logUser = $("div.header-actions  clr-dropdown.dropdown button span"),
       EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
       browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(logUser), 5000);
       logUser.click();

3. var elementToClick = element(by.css('.btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'));
 browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToClick)
 ,10000).then ( function () {elementToClick.click(); });
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: use `element(by.cssContainingText("span","User Name")).click()`

Comment: Unfortunately this also did not work and also the user name keeps changing with every login
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: by.cssContainingText("span", "User Name")
Failures:
1) angularjs homepage todo list login to caas
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: Failures:
1) angularjs homepage todo list login to caas
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:478:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:302:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:262:5)

Comment: Message:
    Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an problem with your css selector.

try this, this should work.

```
element(by.css('div.header-actions > clr-dropdown.dropdown > button.nav-text')).click();
```

Comment: No Luck, I still get the same issue.